# How to sort members of the entity in master data services(mds) by name?

Tags: sorting, sql-server-2012, master-data-services

I want to alphabetically sort members by name of the entity in master data services (mds). I cannot find a straightforward solution. Currently, members are sorted by code (built in mode!?). How to change sort order by name? Please see an example below:

```
Name    Code
c   0
a   1
d   2
l   4
f   5
s   6
m   7
b   8
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

On the Master Data Manager website, you can change how the entities are displayed to change the order they sort. When browsing the entity (using Explorer) that has the column you want to sort, **click Settings**, then change the **display format to Name {Code}**. This applies to all domain-based attributes that are part of the entity.

I have not found a way to do this same thing using the Excel add-in.

Comment: There is now an option to do this in the 2017 version of the Excel Add-in. It's in the settings menu under the Data tab